# Rational homotopy type of a complex algebraic variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Does there exist a simply connected smooth proper complex variety that is not rationally homotopy equivalent to a simply connected smooth proper complex variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Certainly, any such variety should be homotopic to one over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Concerning your actual question, my guess is no. Take a look  at the variety constructed by Serre in "Examples de varieties projective conjuguees non homemorphes". It seems that it wouldn't descend to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I think fake projective planes should be a counterexample to this, since they are characterized by their homotopy type and can't be defined over any real field.

Comment: @WillSawin you are right, I got confused